# Checking if there is any textNodes in body using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I need to check in some fast way if there is ***any*** text nodes on page, excluding white space.
Preferably, I'd like to see if there is a way to do this with jQuery, and to be cross-browser.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if( $.trim($("body").text()).length > 0 ){
  ...
}
```

or, if you want to exclude all white space...

```
$("body").text().replace(/\s/g,'').length > 0 ){
```

Comment: +1 Heh, and I'd been thinking about doing this by checking every node individually. Very nice.